# Parsing sd card file to polymorphic objects

Tags: teensy

I am trying to read a file from sd card and parse them to polymorphic objects, then have an array of pointers to them so i can access them later.

I was wondering what the best format would be to save these objects in, i was looking at https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson but i don't know if it's possible to deserialize them to the right object.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as serialization/deserialization in C++. You can read the data values from an object, and you can write data values to an object, as long as you either expose the properties as `public`, or create "getter" and "setter" member functions.

It is then up to you to store and retrieve that data in whatever form you like.

You could store the raw RAM data that corresponds to an object, however if there are any pointers in that object they will be stored as just that - a pointer - which will be meaningless when reloaded. So it's better to store the data values manually.

How you store the data depends on what the data is. Yes, you can use JSON format if you so choose - it has good abstraction for storing strings, escaping special characters, etc. So it would be quite convenient - however, it's quite a heavyweight arrangement. A lighter method would be to store binary data directly, but that is inflexible and can't easily store different types of data in different ways for different objects.

CSV format is quick and easy to parse, but you have to manually deal with things like commas in data strings, etc.